# Add more custom fields when creating a new custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta

One of my post types needs to be fully customizable, to the extent that when you create a post, you can add more headings. Essentially, I'm making a newspaper with the universal "announcements" entry. However, some days the content manager may want to include another heading (e.g. "lost and found"). I need to have an "Add More" button at the bottom of the new post page which creates a new div with a input for the field and a WYSIWYG for value.

I'm currently using the advanced custom fields, but I'm fairly certain that the plugin does not support an option like this.

Making something like this is rather easy in raw HTML/JS, but I'm wondering what the best way to go about this would be in Wordpress. I already have a custom theme built and all that, I just need some pointing in the right direction when it comes to this. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use "advanced custom fields repeater"? So you can repeat the WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using repeater field of advanced custom field plugin.

See example

[image: ACF repeater fields]

Comment: I'd like to avoid spending extra on plugin upgrades. How should I go about approaching the development of this myself?